# Is there a cross compiler of sorts targetting different versions of Windows (edition, word size etc)?

Tags: windows-7, c++, cross-platform, windows-server, compiler

I am in a situation where I need to rebuild my existing C++ app to target Windows Server 2008. My dev machine is Windows 7 64 bit Home Premium.

The app uses no APIs at all and is in "pure" C++. It's intended to be a cross platform component really, so no UI or files or anything. But I suppose these two Windows versions aren't binary compatible, so there's a need to cross compile.

Is there anything that could help me?

(FYI I am planning to showcase an app on a website that I am currently building. Eventually I'd have web services of some kind, which may need more elaborate and thought out solutions, but for the moment I am planning a quick and dirty CGI way of doing things)

Comment: What makes you think these two versions aren't binary compatible?  They certainly can be (and if your server is 64 bit which it probably is, they should be).

Comment: There is also a small issue of the underlying processor architecture. I don't know the complete configuration, so assumed incompatibility. Anyway, I have put in a query to my host and awaiting the response. Would be great if mine and their OS's are completely compatible.

Comment: Which compiler you are using? I have the same OS and everithing I compile there runs even on XP mashine.